# Hide/Show only closest class

Tags: jquery

I have multiple sets of yes/no radio buttons that hide or show divs based on the radio value. How do I select ONLY the CLOSEST divs to the set of radio buttons that are changed?

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/esLMh/

This works but changes all divs on the page instead of only the closest.

```
$('.hide-show input').change(function() {
  $('.hide-show-yes').toggle(this.value == 'yes');
  $('.hide-show-no').toggle(this.value == 'no');
});
$('.hide-show input:checked').change(); //trigger correct state onload
```

How do I only effect the closest divs to the radio set when there are multiple sets on a page?

```
$('.hide-show input').change(function() {
  $(this).next('.hide-show-yes').toggle(this.value == 'yes').next('hide-show-no').toggle(this.value == 'no');
});
$('.hide-show input:checked').change(); //trigger correct state onload
```

Comment: What do you mean with "closest"?

Comment: And why do you want to hide multiple divs and re-display some of them? Just have 1 div and change the inner html of it.

Comment: ..because i live in the real world and my application is much more complicated than a school practice example.

Comment: I really think you're just making it way more complicated than it is, and most of the people here have more experience than from school practices. I recommend that you read my answer :) And yes.. the real world recommends that you don't do overhead stuff. Creating multiple divs is an OVERHEAD, It's like having 50 functions when you only need 5, It's pointless :)

Comment: So tell me your solution that will fit into multiple ajax tabs and work within a .net framework of separate views dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the next element of parent div of radio button, You can do it this way

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/esLMh/4/)**

```
$('.hide-show input').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('div').next('.hide-show-yes').toggle(this.value == 'yes');
  $(this).closest('div').next('.hide-show-no').toggle(this.value == 'no');
});
$('.hide-show input:checked').change(); //trigger correct state onload
```

Comment: What is the reason for the "no" not toggling to hide in this demo?

Answer (score 0):

Give your input fields an id, you can control the ids so you can do something like

```
$('#radioButtonOne').change(function() {
```

and

```
$('#radioButtonTwo').change(function() {
```

That way you can always be sure to know what is being changed, and you do different function corresponding to the changes.

I also recommend having only ONE div for each state, so you change the text of the div instead of hiding and showing multiple divs.

I also recommend using the on jquery function, so that you can change the DOM but still be able to listen to NEW elements that you might create.

```
 $("#radioButtonOne").on("change", function(event){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hide-show input').change(function() {    
  $(this).parent().next().toggle(this.value == 'yes');
  $(this).parent().next().next().toggle(this.value == 'no');
});
$('.hide-show input:checked').change(); //trigger correct state onload
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/esLMh/6/)